# DevExpress GridView links not working

Tags: gridview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I'm trying out DevExpress GridView following the instructions in their tutorial at https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8998.

The page appears with the GridView showing the data, but none of the links on the GridView are working. Is there a step that I'm forgetting?

UPDATE: Ok I figured out the initial problem. I did not put the @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets and the @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts in the _Layout.cshtml page so that solved the initial problem where the links were not working at all. But now, when I click on any of the pager links, the ...Loading popup appears and stays endlessly. When I click on a Delete link, it only works once, if I click on it again, nothing happens. Same with the Edit and Add links.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the _Layout.cshtml file was the culprit. I assumed DevExpress would do it for me but the problem was that jQuery needed to be rendered before the calls to @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets and the @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts. So I placed them in the head element in _Layout as in the following. Once I did this, the GridView worked.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

@Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.HtmlEditor },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.PivotGrid },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Chart },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Report },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Scheduler },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.TreeList },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Spreadsheet },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.SpellChecker }
)

@Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.HtmlEditor },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.PivotGrid },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Chart },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Report },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Scheduler },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.TreeList },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Spreadsheet },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.SpellChecker }
)
```